# I am missing a .dll file

Tags: windows

i downloaded tor today and installed it. but I cannot run it due to an error. I am for some reason missing the api-ms-win-crt-convert-|1-1-0.dll file. what am I to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the middle of the same problem. Some possibilities: 1) Make sure ALL your OS updates are installed and try again. That would make it a timing issue. 2) Search for an older Tor version 3) Report it to Tor - frontdesk@torproject.org.

other posts on the bug:

https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/dlpmsi/i_just_updated_my_tor_browser_to_the_new_version/

https://steamcommunity.com/app/489830/discussions/0/312265327168390553/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having a hoax binary - I have helped to investigate the hoax binary case, so - **yes, it happens**! Tor expert bundle and Tor Browser **do have them all** shipped and are linked statically, mostly. So - just wipe it out and reinstall. Or - you can make a fully-static Tor build, so it will be just *one* exe file with no dll requirements attached. Check your downloads' HTTPS certificates and signatures - there's a problem **for sure**